# Isabelle: stop simp from splitting a tuple

Tags: isabelle

How can I stop the `simp` method from splitting a tuple into its components?

**Example.** If I write

```
fun foo where "foo z = blah z" 
lemma "∃z :: nat × nat × nat × nat × nat. foo z"
```

the proof state is `∃z. foo z`. If I then write

```
apply (simp)
```

the proof state becomes `∃a aa ab ac b. blah (a, aa, ab, ac, b)`. I like that `simp` has expanded `foo` into `blah`, but I would rather it kept my variable `z` as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the theorem `split_paired_Ex` from the simplifier as in `apply (simp del: split_paired_Ex)`. There is also the theorem `split_paired_All` for the HOL quantifier `ALL` and `split_paired_all` for the meta-quantifier `!!`.